# Is it true that a certain book of the Tanach was rewritten because it was lost?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, authorship

I remember being told that a certain book in the Tanach had to be rewritten after it was lost during the Kings period. Is it considered true? If it is, are there mekorot/academic sources for this?

I tried searching, but my google searches didn't come up with anything.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of Eicha? See [Moed Kattan 26a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/מועד_קטן_כו_א). And wiki here: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/מגילת_איכה

Comment: you're probably thinking of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilkiah

Comment: I seem to recall that reference is made in Scripture to a apparently unknown book of the Bible . Since the names of the Bible are not original--the Torah was one continuous text without chapter or volume designations--it appears that the book being referred to simply pertains to a specific section of the Torah that is now known by a different name. I wish I could recall the names but I don't at this time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Sefer Eicha was destroyed by King Yehoyakim who threw it into a fire and rewritten by Yirmiyahu at the command of Hashem.

[Yirmiyahu 36:23](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16033#v=23&showrashi=true)

> 23: And it came to pass, when Jehudi read three or four verses, he rent it
>   with a scribe's razor, and cast [it] onto the fire which was on the
>   brazier until the entire roll was consumed on the fire that was on the
>   brazier.

**Rashi**

> **three… verses:** Our Rabbis (Moed Katan 26a) stated. This was the Scroll of Lamentations. They read before him, (1:1) “How…(:2) She
>   weeps… (ibid. 3) Judah has been exiled…(ibid. 4) The roads of Zion are
>   mournful.” Despite all this, he was not troubled. He said, “I am the
>   king over the survivors.” As soon as he read (ibid. 5), Her
>   adversaries have become the head, “ he said,” From now on, I am [no
>   longer] the king." Immediately, he rent it with a scribe’s razor.

Then again

> 28: Take for yourself again another roll and write upon it all the
>   original words that were on the first roll, which Jehoiakim the king
>   of Judah, burned.

[The Invisible Man By Rabbi Jack Abramowitz](https://www.ou.org/torah/nach/nach-yomi/jeremiah_chapter_36/)

> The officers went to King Yehoyakim and gave the scroll to the scribe
>   for safekeeping before telling the king its contents. The king had the
>   scroll brought to him and read. (It was winter, so he had a fire
>   burning for warmth.) When only three or four verses had been read
>   (three or four pages, according to the Radak), the king sliced the
>   scroll with a razor and threw the scroll on the fire. He simply wasn’t
>   concerned by what he had heard. Some of his officers asked him not to
>   burn the scroll, but the king would not comply.
>
> King Yehoyakim instructed some of his men to go and get Jeremiah and
>   Baruch, but G-d had hidden them. (The Radak says miraculously. He
>   suggests that G-d enveloped them in darkness or made their pursuers
>   unable to see them.)
>
> G-d told Jeremiah to write the scroll over again, plus a message for
>   Yehoyakim: You burned the scroll because it foretold that
>   Nebuchadnezzar would raze the land. Therefore, G-d says that
>   Yehoyakim’s line would lose the throne and his corpse would be tossed
>   out. Jeremiah re-wrote the scroll, along with the updates. (And, as we
>   know from the Book of Kings, Yehoyakim’s son ruled only three months
>   before he was succeeded by his uncle, Tzidkiyahu. Furthermore, We read
>   more about Yehoyakim’s funeral – or lack thereof – earlier, in chapter
>   22. Remember, these prophecies are not necessarily collected in chronological order!)

Comment: Does not seem to answer the question. I book that was burnt and rewritten is not exactly "lost".